# How to create TFRecords file from png images

Tags: database, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, tensorflow-serving

I'm just started working with TensorFlow a week ago, and I have some basic problems.

The major one is that I didn't find a way to create a TFRecords that contains all my data. I understood that this process is necessary in order to train my own network with few millions 32x32 pixels images.

I've found a lot of tutorials and a lot of documentations referring to the "input_pipeline", but none of those tutorials explained clearly how do I create my own database, with my own images.

I have few major folders and some sub-folders, ~300,000 png images each, where the label is in the name of the image (0 or 1 - binary classification).

The way to get those images is trough the (glob) lines:

```
"/home/roishik/Desktop/database/train/exp*/*png"
"/home/roishik/Desktop/database/train/exp*/tot*/*png"
```

So my question is:

**How do I create a TFRecords file that contains those images and their labels?**

I'll really appreciate your help! I'm stuck with this problem for almost two days, and I found only really specific answers about MNIT and ImageNet.

Thanks!

Comment: Converting to tfrecords is not necessary, TensorFlow queues can efficiently handle individual PNG files -- https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Millions of 32x32 images? Sounds exactly like CIFAR. Check out the [TensorFlow Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim), they have a script to download CIFAR10 and convert it to TFRecords: [download_and_convert_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/download_and_convert_data.py). If your data is not CIFAR, check out the code anyway, it will probably help you.

The code that loads CIFAR10 looks like this:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    image_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint8)
    encoded_image = tf.image.encode_png(image_placeholder)

    with tf.Session('') as sess:
        for j in range(num_images):
            [...] # load image and label from disk
            image = [...]
            label = [...]

            png_string = sess.run(encoded_image,
                                  feed_dict={image_placeholder: image})

            example = dataset_utils.image_to_tfexample(
                png_string, 'png', _IMAGE_SIZE, _IMAGE_SIZE, label)
            tfrecord_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
            [...]
```

The `image_to_tfexample()` function looks like this:

```
def image_to_tfexample(image_data, image_format, height, width, class_id):
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/encoded': bytes_feature(image_data),
        'image/format': bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/class/label': int64_feature(class_id),
        'image/height': int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': int64_feature(width),
    }))
```

And the `int_64_feature()` function looks like that (the `bytes_feature()` function is similar):

```
def int64_feature(values):
    if not isinstance(values, (tuple, list)):
        values = [values]
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=values))
```

**Edit**

A few more details:

- The `TFRecordWriter` is created like so (this also creates the file):

  ```
  with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(training_filename) as tfrecord_writer:
      [...] # use the tfrecord_writer
  ```
- The [documentation for `tf.image.encode_png()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/image.html#encode_png) says that the image should have shape `[height, width, channels]`, where `channels = 1` for grayscale, `channels = 2` for grayscale + alpha, 3 for RGB color, and `channels = 4` for RGB color + alpha (RGBA).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using my own database (SEM grayscale images). does the last line `tfrecord_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())` saves the TFRecords file? where am I giving the file a name? + does the image should be loaded as 32x32 tensor or as 1024 vector?

Comment: My pleasure. I added a couple lines to my answer, it should clarify things for you.